# Reactive Extensions SelectMany and Concat

Tags: c#, system.reactive, reactive-programming, rxjs

I understand that the behaviour of SelectMany is to effectively merge the results of each value produced into a single stream so the ordering in nondeterministic.

How do I do something similar to concatAll in RxJs in C#.

```
var obs = Observable.Range (1, 10).SelectMany (x => {
return Observable.Interval (TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10 - x)).Take (3);
}).Concat();
```

This is effectively what I want to do, Given a Range, Wait a bit for each then concat in the order that they started in. Obviously this is a toy example but the idea is there.

Blair

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `Select`, not `SelectMany`.  The `Concat` overload that you want to use works on an `IObservable<IObservable<T>>`, so simply project the inner sequences, don't flatten them.

```
var obs = Observable.Range(1, 10)
                    .Select(x => Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10 - x)).Take(3))
                    .Concat();
```

Note that the subscrition of each `Interval` is deferred by using `Concat`; i.e., the first `Interval` starts right away when you subscribe, but all of the remaining intervals are generated and enqueued without subscription.  It's not like `Concat` will subscribe to everything and then replay the values in the correct order later.

Comment: +1 That was so helpful. It's important to understand that SelectMany is just Select + Merge. But I needed a Select + Concat. Very easy in Rx =]. (I was just about to add that comment and noticed that that's THE Dave Sexton who wrote that answer. Thanks Dave, your blog posts on Rx are amazing. Thanks to you i'm a fan of Rx!)