# How to define ConcatMap in Rx.Net?

Tags: rx.net

Rx.Net doesn't have a concatMap equivalent as of now, but there is for sure a way to get a similar behavior given the functionality available. I have right now `observable.SelectMany(x => ProcessItemAsync(item).ToObservable())` where `ProcessItemAsync` is an async method, which I'd like to be executed in order one by one and not for all items at once.

If I understand Rx correctly, `observable.ConcatMap(x => ProcessItemAsync(item).ToObservable())` should do that, but it doesn't currently exist in Rx.Net, so what would be another way of achieving the same behavior?

I might have multiple sources for observables, and each of those sources can perform `ProcessItemAsync` in parallel, it should be just within the stream sequential, to preserve the input / output order, so I can't lock it on `ProcessItemAsync`

**Update:**

Given the similar question [Reactive Extensions SelectMany and Concat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26300072/reactive-extensions-selectmany-and-concat) I have made an example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/cG3T2v - using `SemaphoreSlim` is the only way I've managed it to get working.

(here the code from the example)

```cs
using System;
using System.Reactive.Linq;
using System.Reactive.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static readonly SemaphoreSlim semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1);

        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Kinda in order ...");

            var kindaInOrder = Observable.Range(1, 4)
                .Select(x => LongProcessAsync(x).ToObservable())
                .Concat()
                .Do(x => Console.WriteLine($"{x} concatenated"));

            await kindaInOrder.RunAsync(CancellationToken.None);

            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Completely in order ...");

            var completelyInOrder = Observable.Range(1, 4)
                .Select(x => OrderedLongProcessAsync(x).ToObservable())
                .Concat()
                .Do(x => Console.WriteLine($"{x} concatenated"));

            await completelyInOrder.RunAsync(CancellationToken.None);
        }

        static async Task<int> LongProcessAsync(int n)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Job {n} started");
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(4 - n));
            Console.WriteLine($"Job {n} done");

            return n;
        }

        static async Task<int> OrderedLongProcessAsync(int n)
        {
            await semaphore.WaitAsync();
            try
            {
                return await LongProcessAsync(n);
            }
            finally
            {
                semaphore.Release();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think if you replace `LongProcessAsync(x).ToObservable()` with `Observable.Create` you won't need the lock to synchronise the tasks as they will be executed one after another.

Comment: As Stanislav mentioned, the problem seems to be in `LongProcessAsync(x).ToObservable()`. Try with `.Select(x => Observable.FromAsync(() => LongProcessAsync(x)))` instead, so that the Task doesn't actually start before it has been subscribed.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the behaviour of ConcatMap by combining `.Select()` and `.Concat()`.

Paste below to [LINQPad](https://www.linqpad.net/) to try it out

```cs
public void Main()
{
    // Generate 100 items and 'process' async
    Observable
        .Range(0, 100)
        .Select(x => ProcessItemAsync(x))
        .Concat()
        .Dump();
}

private readonly Random _rnd = new Random();

public async Task<int> ProcessItemAsync(int item)
{
    await Task.Delay(_rnd.Next(0, 1000));
    return item;
}
```

The code starts 100 'jobs' that take different times to complete, but you will see that the resulting observable, returns the result in the order that the jobs were started, instead of the order of which they complete, which would be the case if you used `.SelectMany()`

(EDIT: In the original post I made an extension method, that Selected/Mapped the given async Func. Then I made a class where the results were awaited, indexed, and stored, to be emitted in order.
But then I found a much simpler solution here:[Answer to Reactive Extensions SelectMany and Concat](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26301216/6579063), which is the Select Concat combination.)

Comment: Thx, this helped, but it doesn't work to 100%. I do get race condition errors from the processing done in `ProcessItemAsync` - I did add a sempahore into `ProcessItemAsync`, which solves the problem, but that's locking and doesn't feel right, when using Rx. Any other ideas?

Comment: Sorry, no. Are you able to post a simple example that reproduces the racecondition? (Maybe as a new question?) Then somebody might help you figure out why it occurs.

Comment: Hello, I've updated my question with the example, thx for your time

Comment: I don't see the issue, I'm afraid? In both cases 'kindaInOrder' and 'completelyInOrder' I get the Job started in the correct order, and "x concatenated" in the correct order.
Isn't that what you wanted? Having LongProcessAsync running in parallel, preserving input output order?

Comment: The 'completelyInOrder' observable actually runs sequentally taking the collective time of all jobs to run = 6 seconds,  whereas the 'kindaInOrder' runs in parallel, taking the time of the longest job, in this example, which is 3 seconds.

Comment: Right, maybe I wasn't clear enough, I want to preserve the order also for LongProcessAsync. Basically I use it as a task queue and it might be that task 1 takes longer and doesn't make sense after task 2

Comment: Do you mean, that if you have gotten the result of task 2 (before task 1 is finished), you want to cancel task 1 and ignore the result of it?

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain the described behavior (subscribing to each inner generated observable only when the previous one completes) using a combination of `.Select()` and `.Merge()` with the `maxConcurrent` parameter set to 1.

```
static IObservable<TU> ConcatMap<T, TU>(this IObservable<T> source, Func<T, IObservable<TU>> selector) {
    return source.Select(selector).Merge(maxConcurrent: 1);
}
```

To ensure the long running operations are started only after the previous has finished, the selector must return "cold" observables:

```
source.ConcatMap(t => Observable.FromAsync(() => LongProcessAsync(t)))
```

Comment: No.
Select(x).Merge() has the same effect as SelectMany(x).
As stated by the op in the update, it should be Select(x).Concat()

Comment: Yes, the second part of the answer with `FromAsync` is correct but the first is wrong.

Answer (score -1):

To follow up my comment here is the suggested solution.

Instead

```cs
.Select(x => LongProcessAsync(x).ToObservable())
```

use the following:

```cs
.Select(x => Observable.Create<int>(async o =>
{
    try
    {
        var result = await LongProcessAsync(x);
        o.OnNext(result);
        o.OnCompleted();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        o.OnError(ex);
    }
}))
```